# Contact us form not display in Block list of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, admin-panel

I have enabled Contact us form by **Stores => Settings => Configuration => General => choose Contacts =>  Contact Us** and set Enable Contact to 'Yes'.

But **Contact Us Info block** not display in Block section.
What went wrong please suggest.

Comment: Which URL by are you checking the page?

Comment: I am checking it on admin panel BaseURL/admin/cms/block/edit/block_id/4/
In short, i just need to add contact form along with category navigation menu.

Comment: You want to display contact form by static block?

Comment: When you ask a question, you do it not only for yourself. If you finded a solution, please write it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to confugure this if you have the sample data installed is to go into stores, configuration then general contact, enable contact. Then you will find the contact block and edit that. If you don't have the sample data then you need to make a new widget and associate that with a block.

1. Go to Content > Widgets
2. Create new widget and choose CMS Static Block
3. Add layout update to specific page (Contact us Page), Main Content Top Container
4. Choose Static Block